# Assistance with order by and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tasked with finding the running count of transaction.id per unique merchant.id sorted by transaction date in ascending order.
I keep getting error message with my syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT(merchant_id), COUNT(transaction_id) as transactioncount, transaction_datetime  
FROM Salt_transactions$
Group BY merchant_id
ORDER BY transaction_datetime
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT(merchant_id), COUNT(transaction_id) as transactioncount, transaction_datetime  
FROM Salt_transactions$
Group BY merchant_id
ORDER BY transaction_datetime
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` is used to get distinct _rows_. However, your `GROUP BY` has already eliminated all duplicates, so simply do `SELECT`. (And no eyebrows will be raised.)

Comment: You can have multiple `transaction_datetime` per `merchant_id` so which one do you want selected? The latest one?

Comment: I.e. a merchant_id can have different transaction_datetime values, overlapping another merchant_id's transaction_datetime values.

Comment: Ah right - your current query doesn't get a "running count" - it just gets a count. If you want a running count you don't want `Group BY merchant_id` at all. Probably simpler if you supply some example data in `Salt_transactions$` showing multiple rows for a merchant and explain desired end results

Comment: @jarlh didb't show unique ids

Comment: @MartinSmith yes

Comment: The error message is likely that you have `transaction_datetime` in the `SELECT` list but it is not used in the `GROUP BY`. When you use `GROUP BY`, you are only allowed to `SELECT` what was used in the grouping (`merchant_id`), as well as aggregate functions like `COUNT` which you used.